# Simple examples of compactification

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, effective-field-theory, compactification

I am starting out on some research and I am trying to find basic examples of compactification to start off with, and then I want to work my way up to more complicated items such as having an action that includes a field-strength term for a $p$-form (or something along those lines). So, I suppose a concrete question would be the following:

If I had a $D$-dimensional metric and I wanted to separate it into $D = d+1$ spacetime, and I let the compactified direction be spatial such that $X^d \sim  X^d + 1$ (periodic), then how do I get out the following metric: $$ds^2 = G_{MN}dX^MdX^N = e^{2\alpha\phi}g_{\mu\nu}dX^\mu dX^\nu + e^{2\beta\phi}\left(dX^d\right)^2\tag{2.70}$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constrained by the dimensions, but somehow they get chosen (this is all from [The Swampland: Introduction and Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06239) by Palti).

It is also unclear to me how the metric $G_{MN}$ is substituted into the generalized Ricci scalar $R^D$ gives the following action
\begin{equation}
\int d^DX\sqrt{-G}R^D = \int d^dX\sqrt{-g}\left(R^d - \frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2\right).\tag{2.73}
\end{equation}
I have the general understanding that we need to plug in the metric $G_{MN}$ into $G_{MN}R^{MN}$ and then simplify by expanding the components, but it just seems fuzzy to me.

My next question after that would then be how do we include (abelian) gauge fields? For example, if I wanted my **final** action after compactification to be something along the lines of
\begin{equation}
S\sim \int d^dx\sqrt{-g}\left(R - 2\Lambda + c_1 R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu} + c_2R_{\mu\nu\sigma\rho}F^{\mu\nu}F^{\sigma\rho} + \cdots\right),
\end{equation}
what original action would I even start with? Where would I even look for something like that? I know the action I wrote previously is for graviton-photon scattering, but I would like to arrive at that **not** from an phenomenological point of view, but starting from a higher-dimensional action with some coupling, say,
\begin{equation}
S\sim \int d^Dx\sqrt{-G}\left(R^d + R^d_{MN}F^{MN} + \cdots\right)
\end{equation}
where I started with $D$ but performed some KK-compactification and was left with $D\rightarrow 4 + p$ dimensions.

I am just really at a lost on how to do compactifications for really just basic general relativity action in higher dimensions, but then need to work up to those same compactifications in $d$-dimensions involving more complex field strength tensors. Honestly, any reference or answer is appreciated and helpful, thanks!